Are Hausdorff countably compact topological groups always normal?
A colleague and I have a result that shows that for Hausdorff countably compact W-spaces, being a topological group implies normality. But it occurred to us that (being not super experienced working with topological groups) we're unsure whether this is known (or disproven) without the W-space assumption. π-Base is also uncertain:
https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%24T_2%24%2BCountably+compact%2BHas+a+group+topology%2B%7ENormal
So, are Hausdorff countably compact topological groups always normal?

I haven't checked all details, but this should be a counter-example:
Let $\Sigma$ be the
$\Sigma$-product of $ω_1$ copies of the circle group
$\mathbb T$, considered as a subgroup of
$\mathbb T^{\omega_1}$, $G = \Sigma \times \mathbb T^{\omega_1}$.
Of course, $G$ is a Hausdorff topological group.
It is mentioned here, page 5.
According to this paper,
$\Sigma$ is countably compact and $G$ is not normal. Since $\mathbb T^{\omega_1}$ is compact, $G$ is countably compact (Engelking, 3.10.14).
See here for the general definition of $\Sigma$-product and a proof that it is countably compact, if all factors are compact. Of course, in case of groups, the base point in each factor is the identity.

hi Ulli. what is the $\Sigma$-product of a family of groups?

@Atticus Stonestrom: $\Sigma$-product $= {f \in \mathbb T^{\omega_1}: f(\alpha) \neq e \text{ for at most countably many } \alpha }$, where $e = (1,0)$  is the identity element of the circle group.  See for instance here, page 55.

dear Ulli, thanks!

The paper mentions that $G$ is not normal by invoking Tamano's theorem (assuming $\mathbb T^{\omega_1}$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of $\Sigma$), that is, because the group $\Sigma$ is not paracompact.  Any idea why that is the case?

@PatrickR: $\Sigma$ is countably compact, but not compact. Hence, it is not paracompact.

Thanks Ulli! And good news for my result: while $\Sigma$ is a $W$-space (any $\Sigma$-product of $W$-spaces is), $\mathbb T^{\omega_1}$ is not, so $G$ is not a $W$-space.
